# Why is there 2 ways to write a Pointer to Constant, but only one way to write Constant Pointers?

Tags: c, constants, declaration, qualifiers

A Pointer to Constant can be written in either these two ways:

```
int a = 5;

const int* b = &a;
/* or */
int const* c = &a;
```

But a Constant Pointer can only be written in this way:

```
int a = 5;

int* const b = &a;

// const* int c = &a; This will not compile.
```

The second line will create this error:

```
expected identifier or '(' before 'int'
```

Why is this not allowed?

Comment: Do you think that `* int c = &a;` should be valid and the same as `int* c = &a;`? If not, then why do you think your question has anything to do with `const`?

Comment: `const* int c = &a;` is a syntax error. The correct syntax is: `const int *c = &a;`

Comment: `int const*` is unfortunate but shit happens...

Comment: @4386427 is it considered an unusual way of writing it?

Comment: I can't give you statistics but I'll never use that form and it wouldn't pass review at my work.

Comment: You can write `long unsigned int long` as a type; it isn't a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C declaration is defined the following way

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list
```

For example in this declaration

```
const int* b = &a;
```

`const int` are type specifiers and `( *b ) = &a` is the init-declarator-list.

You may rewrite the above declaration like

```
const int ( *b ) = &a;
```

If you want to make the declarator a constant object you should to write

```
const int ( * const b ) = &a;
```

You may not separate a declarator using a type specifier (except using a qualifier) like

```
const* int c = &a;
```

That is in this record the type specifier `int` splits the declarator `*c`.

On the other hand, you could introduce a type specifier the following way

```
typedef const int *Ptr;
```

In this case you can make the declarator constant writing

```
const Ptr b = &a;
```

In this case you will get the same declaration as

```
const int * const b = &a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaration specifiers can occur in any order.  As a matter of style we tend to put storage class specifiers first, followed by type qualifiers, followed by type specifiers, as in

```
static const volatile unsigned long int *p;
```

but the compiler doesn’t care - we could write it as

```
unsigned long int volatile static const *p;
```

and the compiler will be happy with it (anyone reading and maintaining your code may not be).

The `*` is part of the *declarator*, not the declaration specifiers - it is bound to `p` regardless of how the declaration specifiers are ordered.  If we want to declare `p` as a `const` pointer, then we must apply the `const` keyword as part of the declarator.  To prevent confusion with declaring a pointer to `const`, the rule is that if we’re making the *pointer* `const`, then the `const` keyword goes to the *right* of the `*` operator:

```
const T *p;  // p is a pointer to const T
T const *p;  // same as above

T * const p; // p is a const pointer to T.
```